# unanswered questions

Tags: support

I had a look at the [unanswered question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/unanswered), but I noticed half of them seem to have an answer after all, some even two. Why are they listed there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an answer with at least 2 upvotes before it is considered answered. The assumption being that if it has not received 2 upvotes it is not answering the question well.

Comment: OK, that's clear, thanks.

Comment: I thought it was necessary to have an accepted answer, but this way seems smarter

Comment: @clabacchio - There are quite some OPs who fail to accept answers. In that case it's a good idea to rely on the community.

Comment: @stevenvh, I am looking for a solid source that I learned this from a year ago, I believe them accepting an answer also marks it as answered. It used to be a major component of determining how a beta was going so it was of interest until we graduated. Now that we are graduated we have less worry, although keeping the number up is always useful.

Comment: While this may be true, it is kind of dumb... A lot of the time, there are no votes on any answers whether they are good, bad, accepted, or otherwise. The wording needs changed to provide better clarification. For example, rather than "unanswered questions" why not "unresolved questions"? An answer is an answer whether it is good or not.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier I dont agree, if a question does not have an accepted or upvoted answer then it has not been answered yet, makes sense. If the answer was good then it would have upvotes, if you click on the question and it has a good answer, upvote.

Comment: @Kortuk I'm not disagreeing with your concept, just the language in use. "Unanswered" is not the same as "No good answers" and that language is confusing to users who don't understand what is going on. Besides, it has already been well established in meta that EE.SE users are not very good at upvoting...

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier some of the community feels we are poor voters, not that we are all bad voters. We are discerning. It is semantics in my opinion. Unanswered means no answer. You define that as non posted, I define that as no answer that meets the criteria of the question. I will stop beating a dead horse, maybe a small explanation on the side of the screen.

Comment: The naming is just plain WRONG.  Semantics and personal preferences have little to do with it.  Just below this comment box is the bread and butter box of SE and it is clearly labelled ANSWER.  If that box has been used the QUESTION is no longer unanswered.  We all agree that some answers are no good but they were entered as answers.  The trivial fix is to have two listing parametrs, one for unanswered and one for unresolved then all are happy and the engineers "logic in unassailable".

Comment: @KalleMP I cant count the number of times someone asked a question in the real world and someone responding did nothing to answer it. If there is something written, but no one agrees it is an answer, they asker is still lacking an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Once you open the unanswered questions list, you have to click on ["no answers" tab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) to see questions which don't have any answers.

Comment: I'd never noticed that before, I'd always just pressed the unanswered tab from the main questions page and hadn't paid much attention to the seperate unanswered page assuming they were the same.